# Unable to cast object of type VB$AnonymousDelegate to type System.Func

Tags: vb.net, implicit-conversion, lambda

`AndFunc2` (my original) works fine, but for some reason I don't understand `AndFunc` generates a runtime `InvalidCastException` of "Unable to cast object of type '`VB$AnonymousDelegate_3 2'[System.Int32,System.Boolean]` to type `System.Func'2[System.Int32,System.Boolean]`"

Such implicit conversions of `Function()` to a `Func` generally work for me, but this one doesn't.  I'm wondering why that is, and if there's a way to explicitly cast to get around this problem?

For the record, this fails the same way in VB.NET 2008 and VB.NET 2012.

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("My func: " & AndFunc2(Function(a As Integer) First(a), Function(b) Second(b))(5))
    Console.WriteLine("My func: " & AndFunc(Function(a As Integer) First(a), Function(b) Second(b))(5))
End Sub

Function First(ByVal a As Integer) As Boolean
    Console.WriteLine(a)
    Return False
End Function

Function Second(ByVal a As Integer) As Boolean
    Console.WriteLine(a)
    Return False
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function AndFunc(Of T)(ByVal f1 As Func(Of T, Boolean), ByVal f2 As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As Func(Of T, Boolean)
    Return BoolFunc(Of T)(Function(b1 As Boolean, b2 As Boolean) b1 AndAlso b2, f1, f2)
End Function

Public Function BoolFunc(Of T)(ByVal bfunc As Func(Of Boolean, Boolean, Boolean), ByVal f1 As Func(Of T, Boolean), ByVal f2 As Func(Of T, Boolean))
    If f1 Is Nothing Then Return f2
    If f2 Is Nothing Then Return f1

    Return Function(param As T) bfunc(f1(param), f2(param))
End Function

<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function AndFunc2(Of T)(ByVal f1 As Func(Of T, Boolean), ByVal f2 As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As Func(Of T, Boolean)
    If f1 Is Nothing Then Return f2
    If f2 Is Nothing Then Return f1

    Return Function(param As T) f1(param) AndAlso f2(param)
End Function
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you want this code for? Why making it so unnecesarily intrincate? It is actually required or is just to prove/understand/test a point?

Comment: I'm using these to build `IEnumerable.Where()` filter functions comprised of several optional pieces (basically search options).  The `AndFunc` is definitely useful.  No use for other Boolean comparisons yet though.  I'd still very much like to know why this isn't working and have it up my sleeve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Function() to a Func" is not an implicit conversion precisely, but the normal assignation which `Func` expects (that is, a `Function`).

You are not including the `As Func(Of T, Boolean)` bit in `BoolFunc`, what makes this function "anonymous" (you are not saying explicitly the returned type). Include this bit and it should work without any problem. That is, replace your `BoolFunc` with this one:

```
Public Function BoolFunc(Of T)(ByVal bfunc As Func(Of Boolean, Boolean, Boolean), ByVal f1 As Func(Of T, Boolean), ByVal f2 As Func(Of T, Boolean)) As Func(Of T, Boolean)
    If f1 Is Nothing Then Return f2
    If f2 Is Nothing Then Return f1

    Return Function(param As T) bfunc(f1(param), f2(param))
End Function
```

Comment: Ah geez, I totally glossed over including the return type!  I think my brain was tricked by the identical signature of the third parameter... Yet another case where the "simplicity" of VB.NET is its own worst enemy.

Comment: @j.i.h. This is absolutely normal (not talking about the VB.NET peculiarities, but about you missing this bit), your code is pretty complex; that's why I asked you about the reason for making it in this way: so complex codes give lots of problems while debugging.